# Javascript variable values changing between two console.log() lines

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I'm using [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree), and I'm creating a new node using the [ExtEdit extension](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtEdit). The title (main text) of the node appears to be set correctly, but the value consistently changes between two `console.log()` statements and the wrong value is being sent to the server.

What's going on here? This is boggling my mind.

[Here's](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html) the `FancytreeNode` API.

This is the full function I'm using:

```
function createNode(data) {
    console.log('this is the data object');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('this is data.node.title');
    console.log(data.node.title);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            name: data.node.title,
            parentId: data.node.parent !== undefined ? data.node.parent.key : null
        },
        url: '/my/url'
    }).success(function (thisData, status, jqXHR) {
        data.node.key = thisData.id;
    });
}
```

This is the output. Notice how `data.node.title` is different.

[image: Mind-boggling result]

Comment: Console.log takes a reference as data is an object while data.node.title is a string . To know the value at an exact time, clone it (you can do it with toJSON(stringify))

Comment: @Nevosis, it's `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: @Nevosis I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. I've never had an issue in the past where the two values were different like this. I thought console.log simply output the object/string as it currently exists. I don't understand why `JSON.stringify(data)` would return a different value.

Comment: @Nevosis Ultimately, I don't understand how I would send the value to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out from the comment by Nevosis. When an object is logged using `console.log()`, it is not actually evaluated--it's only a *reference*. The Fancytree event that causes the function to fire acts a little strangely; `data.node.title` isn't set to the new value until the event finishes, but I wasn't expanding the object in the console until after that point. `data.node.title` when logged directly is evaluated (because it has to be), which is why the value was different. I was able to see the correct `data` object by setting a breakpoint immediately after that `console.log()`.